# How can I get the coordinate information of model.visualize_topics() function - BERTopic

Tags: python, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I am trying to get the coordinate informations of the docs placed on the graph by model.visualize_topics() for my BERTopic topic analysis project. Is there any way to see the source code of the function and save the coordinates to use for more advanced analysis?

I found following code as the source code of the visualize_topics() function. But there is not any information about the coordinates in it.

````
def visualize_topics(self,
                     topics: List[int] = None,
                     top_n_topics: int = None,
                     width: int = 650,
                     height: int = 650) -> go.Figure:
    """ Visualize topics, their sizes, and their corresponding words

    This visualization is highly inspired by LDAvis, a great visualization
    technique typically reserved for LDA.

    Arguments:
        topics: A selection of topics to visualize
        top_n_topics: Only select the top n most frequent topics
        width: The width of the figure.
        height: The height of the figure.

    Examples:

    To visualize the topics simply run:

    ```python
    topic_model.visualize_topics()
    ```

    Or if you want to save the resulting figure:

    ```python
    fig = topic_model.visualize_topics()
    fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")
    ```
    """
    check_is_fitted(self)
    return plotting.visualize_topics(self,
                                     topics=topics,
                                     top_n_topics=top_n_topics,
                                     width=width,
                                     height=height)
````

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow for modularity in BERTopic the plotting was separated of the main functions. You can find all information about plotting in BERTopic [here](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/tree/master/bertopic/plotting) and, more specifically, you can find the code for `plotting.visualize_topics` [here](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/master/bertopic/plotting/_topics.py).

Having said that, part of that function is creating the coordinate system as follows:

```py
embeddings = topic_model.c_tf_idf_.toarray()[indices]
    embeddings = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(embeddings)
    embeddings = UMAP(n_neighbors=2, n_components=2, metric='hellinger').fit_transform(embeddings)
```

Here, it takes the c-TF-IDF representation of all topics, scales them and finally uses dimensionality reduction with UMAP using Hellinger distance to map the representation into 2-dimensional space. One thing to note though is that no `random_state` is set in UMAP which results in a stochastic process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not want to use reduced embeddings by UMAP to visualize the data. I tried it with different parameters but I could not find the best parameter to get the best result for my dataset. I want to get the coordinate information of 'topic_model.visualize_documents(docs, embeddings=embeddings)'. Because the output graph make more sense when I run it with original embeddings instead of reduced embeddings. I don't know which kind of reducing algorithm is used by .visualize_documents() function.

Comment: So, I want to get the coordinate information of nodes when I run the visualization functions of BERTopic by using original embeddings.